# CollectionView header stop refreshing/ reloading data when is scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Is there a way to stop refreshing data on my header in collection view? 
The header in my collection view contains data and buttons that is not taking them away from the view. When you scroll down, the collection view reloads the data and any activated buttons on my collection view header gets deactivated.
How can I stop refreshing data on the header until the header bottom reach below navigation controller? Or something like that, to give enough time to see the information on header.

Comment: Issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reloadSections** or **reloadItemsAtIndexpaths** inbuild methods of UICollectionView if you don't want to reload your collectionview

Answer (score 0):

When your header is ended displaying then it will call you can perform your task after hidden:-

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView view: UICollectionReusableView, forElementOfKind elementKind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

OR

You can use dispatch_after for enough time like after 1 second you can do anything:-

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    print("test")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to stop reloading headerView of collectionView which is against code flow.Don't do that.

**How to achieve your goal?**

Save it anywhere.you can use NSUserDefaults to save your button's Activated or deactivated state.